# Validation (HTML5): element 'amp-img' is not supported error

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to convert my html page with the extension aspx to amp html and am constantly getting the error mentioned above. What is the solution?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Which validator are you using? `amp-img` is not a standard HTML element, maybe that's why it errors, but all browsers will just ignore that

Comment: This is an IDE level error? right